# I would like to apply the simulation of softening, melting, and extrusion only to the part that is pushed

Tags: animation

Please see the image of the animation flow.[image]

Object A comes down from above, pushes objects B, C, and D, and adheres to object E. At this point, objects C and D soften and melt.

At this point, objects C and D become soft and melt. (They do not become liquid. Image of very soft slime)
Object B is unchanging.

In addition, object A pushes objects B, C, and D, causing some of the softened and melted objects B and C to be pushed outward.

However, only the parts of objects B and C that are softened, melted, and pushed outward are the parts that object A touches.

As a result, the layer consisting of objects B, C, and D becomes a layer about 2/3 of the thickness.

[Question]

How do I specify that only the parts of objects C and D that touch object A should change? (Even if I select some of the Vertex in Edit Mode, Physics could not be applied.)

Comment: There are some rule in this site. I didn't make the rules and i cannot say i like them...but i think they will close your question. One rule is: you should only ask one question. You asked at least 4 questions...

Comment: Thanks! okay I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possibility (of several) is to use a liquid with some viscosity settings.

You can even animate the viscosity (so high value before the cylinder press hits it and less high if it hits).

Here are some examples of different viscosity, in which i pushed a cylinder from above (as you did in your sketch):

Viscosity: 0.01

[image]

Viscosity: 0.05

[image]

Viscosity: 0.1

[image]

Viscosity: 1

[image]

Note: with the current state of the physics engine i do not think that it is possible to make this all with one simulation. So i think you have to "kind of" fake it. That's what 99% of all blockbusters do and that's what vfx is ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
I had no idea what I was doing, so just knowing that this animation could not be expressed in a single simulation was a very useful hint.

I'm going to bed now, so I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Mr. Chiris
Good morning.

I've been researching and trying Quick Liquid, but I'm having trouble getting the animation that you've shared.
Also, am I correct in understanding that you are using the Force Field Wind to push the center part from above?

Is there anything else I need to set other than Viscosity in Liquid?
If you don't mind, I'd like to know the values you set.

Comment: I have researched and found that Force Filed does not affect Fluid(Liquid), but how do you recess the center?

Just adjusting Viscosity doesn't make it look like the gif you shared.

Comment: you are right, sorry, forgot to mention that i pushed a cylinder from above in the fluid. Added the blend file and corrected my text.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I've been eagerly awaiting you...!!

I will try the blend file now.
I will reply again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I've got the general framework as shown in the GIF, but I still have a problem: 1.

I want to make it look like C and D are hard (keeping the shape of the square) until object A and C and D touch. (Even if I set the viscosity to 5, which is the maximum, it still looks soft...)

Or can I set the start of the simulation to any frame instead of tweaking the simulation settings?

Image:https://ibb.co/QMNH9rV

Comment: Yes you can. It is in the domain settings. Open Cache settings.

Comment: Ohh it worked!! Thank you so much again!! 

Comment: Glad I could help. Please click on the checkmark left to my answer, if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Ohh sorry I forgot it! Thank you Mr. Chiris!

Comment: you are welcome